# does twilio api provides a way to calculate incoming calls per queue?

Tags: typescript, twilio, twilio-api

We need a dashboard view (Can we get some of this data from Twilio APIs?)

- Total # of incoming calls per queue
- Total # of answered calls per queue
- Average call duration per queue

Answer (score 0):

Twilio provides the Average Hold Time with the [Queue Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/queue-resource?code-sample=code-fetch-a-queue-resource&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x):

```
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var queue = QueueResource.Fetch(pathSid: "QUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

The above code will return:

```
{
  
  "average_wait_time": 0,
  "current_size": 0      
}
```

A better option is for your application to keep track of the Total # of incoming calls per queue, the Total # of answered calls per queue, and Average call duration per queue by using the [Status Callback webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/getting-started-twilio-webhooks).

After you register the webhook endpoint, Twilio will make a Status Callback webhook for each inbound phonecall - add the webhook endpoint in the Twilio Console for the phone number.

You will take a similar approach each time a call leaves a queue using [Enqueue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue#attributes-action).

Likewise, and this is a bit counterintuitive, the [WaitUrl of the Enqueue verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue#attributes-waiturl-parameters) will also receive the average wait time and current queue size. You can use the WaitUrl to play the hold music or greeting the caller hears while waiting on hold.